# Android NDK game engine

Tags: android, c++, 3d, linderdaum

I need android ndk 3D game engine with physics, is realy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Game engine for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206089/game-engine-for-android)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206089/game-engine-for-android) has a comprehensive list of game engines for Android.

Comment: I needed portet linux 3d engine to android

Comment: both links aren't valid now, vote to reopen

Answer (score 8):

As one of the developers i will recommend [Linderdaum Engine](http://www.linderdaum.com). It is an 2D/3D open source engine in C++ for Windows and Android. Box2D is integrated in some demos (see SDK). 3D physics engine, like ODE, can be integrated relatively easy. Examples of games can be found on [Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Linderdaum).